# do you have any good practice to improve the productivity of angular 2 development?

Tags: angular

When developing a new website, firstly we often design the layout using Photoshop, then we "split" the whole layout to html + css + images. In our project, we chose Angular2. According to the tutorial of Angular2 website, I tried to split the htmls to Angular2 components. For example, we have a list:

```
<citi-list>
    <citi-detail>
    </citi-detail>
</citi-list>
```

It should be converted into Angular2 Components like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CitiDetailComponent } from '/citi-list/citi-detail';
@Component({
  selector:'citi-list',
  template:`

        <citi-detail>
        </citi-detail>

  `,
  directives: [citi-detail],
  styles: []
})export class CitiListComponent {

}


@Component({
  selector:'citi-detail',
  template:`


  `,
  directives: [],
  styles: []
})export class CitiDetailComponent {

}
```

But we have so many components to write. In order to improve the productivity, I wrote a component generator:
https://github.com/jasondu168/ngen

By using the generator, I could generate the skeleton code from html files directly.

The problem is after changing the html layout, many of the components should also be changed to meet the new requirement. In this case, I can't use the generator any more.

My question is:
Do you have any good practice to improve the development speed of Angular2 components? Do you have any good idea if the html layout changed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet but will be [read here about it](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7482)